# ActionLink en forma de Ruteo por parametros en vez de QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando hacer que al utilizar un `ActionLink` con múltiples parámetros me me genere un link de la forma

```
{Controller}/{Action}/{idCompania}/{idLocal}/{fecha}
```

Pero siempre me genera una *querystring*:

```
{Controller}/{Action}?idCompania=0&idLocal=21&fecha=23-12-2015
```

En el `global.asax` tengo:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "UltimosInformesDetail",
            "UltimosInformes/Details/{idCompania}/{idLocal}/{fecha}",
            new { controller = "UltimosInformes", 
                  action = "Details", 
                  idCompania="", 
                  idLocal="", 
                  fecha="" },
            null
)
```

Mi `ActionLink` en la vista:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Detalle", 
                     "Details",
                     "UltimosInformes", 
                     new { idCompania = item.Compania, 
                           idLocal    = item.Local.Codigo, 
                           fecha      = item.Fecha.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}, null)
</td>
```

Mi `controller`:

```
    public ActionResult Details(short idCompania, short idLocal,string fecha)
    {
        var s = RootContext.Instance.Resolve<ProblemaService>();

        return View(s.ObtenerAuditoresVisita(idCompania, idLocal, DateTime.Parse(fecha)));
    }
```

> Investigué en SO en inglés [ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499385/1913893) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586374/1913893) **Pero no pude resolverlo**

No logro hacer que genere el link "ruteado" siempre me genera una *querystring*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He probado tu ruta y la sintaxis esta bien.

Lo único que posiblemente genere el error es que la ruta `"UltimosInformesDetail"` que has creado la has registado después que la ruta por defecto

Siempre deben ir las rutas **más especificas primero**, luego las más generales y al final (si todavía la necesitas) la ruta por defecto.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UltimosInformesDetail",
    "UltimosInformes/Details/{idCompania}/{idLocal}/{fecha}",
    new
    {
        controller = "UltimosInformes",
        action = "Details",
        idCompania = "",
        idLocal = "",
        fecha = ""
    },
    null
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Era eso @CarlosMuñoz,  tenia mal el orden de los mapeos. Gracias!

Comment: Como puedo enviar parámetros si estoy usando áreas?

Comment: @TomCheca bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, deberías formularla como tal. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [answer] y [ask].